# WT2003S mp3 greeting card

Tags: circuit-design, audio

I'm busy helping a friend with a project involving a cheap mp3 playback circuit based on the WT2003.
[image: photo of PCB]
The original design is based on an LDR which shorts an amplifier circuit and initiates playback, we are modifying it so that the playback is linked to a switch. The issue that I'm running into is the circuit itself is designed to continually loop the audio track while the circuit is open.
Can anyone think of a convenient way to ensure the audio clip only plays once?

Tl;dr: I'm in need of a circuit which transitions from closed to open circuit in a controllable way

Comment: If you are using UART to do the control, you can do the following: Specifying address play, specifying root directory file name, specifying inter-cut address to play, volume level, previous and next, ***stop playing, loop mode***.

Comment: we didn't actually design the circuit ourselves, we are just circuit-bashing the greeting card to suit my friends needs better... If I'm completely honest I don't know if theres going to be a super clean way to solve this problem (short of modifying the entire circuit, rather than just the LDR) that works in the way we're hoping...

Comment: Ah, there is some misunderstanding. My experience about voice chips is on Aliexpres's cheapy assembled modules.  Usually you use Arduino/Rpi to command the voice module using UART/SPI/I2C commands to play, stop, loop etc. But in your case, if it is an greeting card, then I guess when you "open" the card, a switch is open, and voice starts once or loops. So on wordaround is to use a timer, says 555 timer to close the switch, and stops the voice/music. Of course you can also use Arduino to do more control things. Perhaps you can give us a picture of the greeting card. BTW, what is LDR?

Comment: LDR: Light Dependent Resistor, or photoresistor

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look at the [WT2003S datasheet](http://www.electronics123.net/amazon/datasheet/WT2003S-16S_Chip_V1.03.pdf), and there is a command to change if the music should loop or not:

[image: Play mode command]

Unfortunately, it looks like this doesn't persist between restarts of the device. As you can see above, they suggest using an external MCU to run the play mode command every time your circuit powers on, which would work but is probably too complex for what you want to do here.

Interestingly, the datasheet seems to suggest that "single play, no loop playback" is the default. This makes me wonder if they got a customized version of the chip, which the datasheet suggests is possible? That would probably mean you could swap the WT2003S with a new, factory default one...but at that point I suppose you could just get a new playback circuit anyways.

Apart from that, the only other options I can think of would be to add a long duration of silence at the end of the MP3 track, or, like mentioned in the comments, to use a timer circuit to close the switch after a certain amount of time has passed.